# How to orient a globe of the earth so that maximum land mass is visible?

Tags: continent

If you are viewing the world map on globe, where should you place the center of visible hemisphere so that the maximum land mass is visible. I think this should be somewhere near the [Eurasian point of inaccessibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_of_inaccessibility#Eurasia).

Comment: There are two ways of answering this question. In one case “how much of the circular projection of the globe appears filled with land”; in another, “if we measured the area of every piece of land on the hemisphere facing the observer, how large would that be”? The latter formulation would favor solutions with lots of land mass near the edge. Which do you mean to ask about?

Comment: Highly related, if not a duplicate: [Half of Earth with most landmass](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/8226), or [Is there a hemisphere where there's more land than ocean?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17237) and possibly others.